# Calling jQuery Function with Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, getjson

Having some trouble getting this to work, specifically with $.getJSON(). I want to wrap the getJSON function from jQuery in a Javascript function like so:

```
function reload_data() {
    $.getJSON("data/source", function(data) {
        $.d = data;
    });
}
```

But when I call reload_data() it doesn't execute the jQuery function inside. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know it isn't executing the function? Did you put a breakpoint on the line inside to check?

Comment: It's executing just fine. I guess it must be something about the data in the $.d variable not getting refreshed in a way that the rest of the script can use it.

Comment: You're not showing us enough of the picture to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Why are you hanging your "d" variable onto the jQuery namespace, by the way?

Answer (score 3):

You're not telling us enough.  I will just take a guess!

If you are calling this function, and then immediately checking $.d for the results, that is not going to work because you don't allow time for the *asynchronous* AJAX request to complete...

```
reload_data();
alert($.d); // What?!  It's not displaying the updated results?!
```

You'll have to utilize a callback structure, like jQuery uses, in order to make it work...

```
reload_data(function() {
  alert($.d);
});

function reload_data(func) {
  $.getJSON("data/source", function(data) {
    $.d = data;
    //Execute the callback, now that this functions job is done
    if(func)
      func();
  });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess too. That's why I asked if he was sure the function wasn't getting called. After all, Ajax is async.

Comment: That brings up an interesting point.  I think he could change his request to be synchronous and that might fix the issue, although I don't think that's the best solution so I will leave my answer as is.

Comment: Either way, he's going to have to wait for the ajax to be performed before he can do anything with the variable. I think (but I'm not sure) that the browser's UI will be more responsive if the call is left async.

Comment: Absolutely.  The async requests are smooth, sync ones cause the browser to hang.

Answer (score 2):

Put an Alert in side the function to know its getting called.

and a try catch around the jQuery call to see if there is an error

```
function reload_data() {
    alert('reload_data  start');
    try{
        $.getJSON("data/source", function(data) {
            $.d = data;
        });
     }
     catch (ex){
         alert ('error in jQuery call:' + ex)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, but the solution was actually really simple. It was just a matter of synchronization. The page was reloading before the JSON data got reloaded, so that's why I wasn't seeing an error.